# How to handle webhook fulfillment in Dialogflow using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am looking for some advice on how to design the code to handle the fulfillment of requests sent by Dialogflow to my server. Dialogflow only lets setup a single webhook to handle all the intents. Let's say that I have 5 different intents; all of them will call the same webhook on my server. Now, how can I elegantly manage server-side different workflows depending on the intent?
The parameter that I would ideally use to make a distinction is contained in `req.body.queryResult.intent.displayName;` and indicates the name of the current intent. Right now I have two ideas, using express redirect method using the intent as part of the path, or creating a dictionary of handlers where the intents are the key.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment) library, although deprecated, uses your latter approach - creating a Map from Intent name to Handler function and handing this map to a Dispatcher. It is a simple, straightforward, and speedy approach.

The [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) library takes a similar, tho more expansive, approach, letting you register a handler against either the Intent name or the Action value assigned and having separate configurations for the response based on either Intent, Action, or another value that is set in the handler.

Redirecting to a new, path-based, method does not seem to give you anything.